# ng build --prod --base -href works for Chrome but not IE

Tags: angular, sharepoint

Using Angular 5, I have built a solution and want to deploy it to a server. Using `ng build --prod --base-href=https:test.com/_catalogs/masterpage/Custom/ng5qrcode/dist` I have moved the `dist` folder to the correct path and added the index.html file to a SharePoint web part which works in Chrome correctly, but in IE the CSS and JS paths are being referenced as `https://test.com/Pages/CSSorJSfilename`. The SharePoint page's URL is `https://test.com/Pages/ng5qrcode.aspx`

I'm using all the recommended polyfills:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/animation`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.
```

Without changing the index.html file paths every time I make a new build, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4630

Comment: DId you try --deploy-url option?